# SSIS dynamic connection string

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm trying to make a dynamic connection to DB for all of my packages. I'm trying to achieve this by loading my user defined variables with a Script Component .

I know I can also use environment variables to do this, the problem is that not all of my packages will be scheduled and some of them I run with a web service or a procedure, so I can't use a scheduled job to do this, and using the @reference_id is a bit complicate to maintain.

I have no idea how can I loop the variables. I tried

foreach (Variable var in Variables)

But that's not the way ..
So I have two questions here:

- How do I loop all the variables I passed?
- How do I get the Variable name out of it ? (I don't see a name attribute on Variables.VarName.?)

E.G. The OLE DB source will return two rows:

```
conName | conString
 con1   |  someConnection
 con2   |  someConnection
```

And I have two user defined variables in my project -> con1 and con2 .
So, iterate through my varaibles -> foreach(variable) , if var.name = row.conName , load with row.conString value .

Comment: Variables.YourVarialbName

Comment: @plaidDK It should be dynamic. The variable names can change, that's why I need to loop them all .

Comment: But you cannot loop an variable unless its an object

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2015/04/20/using-the-ssis-object-variable-as-a-data-flow-source/

Comment: @plaidDK Look at my answer, this is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've managed to do this. For those of you who will want to do the same, here is what I did :

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

    Dictionary<string, string> AllCons = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        string connectionString;

        foreach (IDTSVariable100 obj in ReadWriteVariables)
        {
            if (AllCons.TryGetValue(obj.QualifiedName, out connectionString))
            {
                obj.Value = connectionString;
            }
        }
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        AllCons.Add("User::" + Row.ConName, Row.ConString);
    }
}
```

I used a Dictionary object to store the connection name and connection string on the `Input0_ProcessInputRow` section. Then, in the PostExecute, I've iterated through all of my User Defined Variables using an `IDTSVariable100` Object. I then checked, if the connection name equals the variable, put the connection string in it.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Glad you got it to work. You could do the same as in the link i posted. Where you set your object to a datatable :)